# How do I place the objects in the array around the center image?

Tags: ios, swift, layout

I have an array of buttons and when I append them to a view I want the to be positioned around a image view which is in the center. Based on how many objects there are in the array, I want them to be evenly spaced around the whole circle. Below is my attempt to do so. What am I doing wrong and how should I fix it? There is more than one button behind the moose.

[image]

```
var userbutton = [UIButton]()
var upimage = [UIImage]()
var locationpic = [AnyObject]()

 func locationsSet(){

    for (index, users) in upimage.enumerate() {

        let userbutton = UIButton()
        userbutton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        userbutton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)
        userbutton.layer.cornerRadius = userbutton.frame.size.width/2
        userbutton.clipsToBounds = true
        userbutton.setImage(users, forState: .Normal)

        let radians = CGFloat(M_PI) * 2.0 / CGFloat(upimage.count) * CGFloat(index)

        let centerx = self.view.bounds.width / 2.0
        let radius =  currentuserpic.frame.size.width / 2.0
        let centery = self.view.bounds.height / 2.0

        let pointx = centerx + cos(radians) * (radius + 40)
        let pointy = (centery) + (sin(radians)) * (radius + 40)

        userbutton.center.x = pointx
        userbutton.center.y = pointy

        self.userbutton.append(userbutton)
        self.view.addSubview(userbutton)

        print("x\(pointx)")
        print("y\(pointy)")


    }


}
```

Comment: This is not from a tutorial.

Comment: This is not homework. This is my own personal app.

Comment: I'm stuck I am not asking you to write the code, I am just trying to figure out how to have the buttons in the array be positioned at a certain position based on how many objects are in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I would do this:

Create an extension to UIView to get the diagonal and radius. These are handy because we want our "satellites" to have predictable placing even when the "planet" isn't square.

```
extension UIView {

    var diagonal : CGFloat {
        return sqrt(pow(self.frame.width, 2) + pow(self.frame.height, 2))
    }

    var radius : CGFloat {
        return diagonal / 2
    }
}
```

---

This will return a point based on an angle and a distance from an origin.
It uses dreadful trigonometry.

```
func getPoint(fromPoint point: CGPoint, atDistance distance: CGFloat, withAngleRadians angle:CGFloat) -> CGPoint {

    let x = point.x
    let y = point.y

    let dx = (distance * cos(angle))
    let dy = (distance * sin(angle))

    return CGPoint(x: (dx + x), y: (dy + y))
}
```

---

Now the real function. Generate a bunch of points in a circle pattern. I used a running sum for the angle instead of multiplying each time by the index. This just returns the centre points for the views.

```
func encirclePoint(point : CGPoint, distance:CGFloat, inParts parts: Int) -> [CGPoint] {

    let angle = 2 * CGFloat(M_PI) / CGFloat(parts) // critical part, you need radians for trigonometry
    var runningAngle : CGFloat = -(CGFloat(M_PI) / 2) // start at the top

    var points : [CGPoint] = []

    for _ in 0..<parts {
        let circlePoint = getPoint(fromPoint: point, atDistance: distance, withAngleRadians: runningAngle)
        points.append(circlePoint)
        runningAngle += angle
    }

    return points
}
```

---

Now you can create a simple function that takes a view, a margin and an array of "satellite" views. It will set their centre and add them to the superview of the view we used to input. It makes sense not to add them to the view itself since they might not be placed inside it.

```
func encircleView(view : UIView, withSubViews subViews : [UIView], withMargin margin : CGFloat) {

    guard !(subViews.isEmpty) else { // if there are no subviews : abort
        return
    }

    let distance = view.radius + margin
    let points = encirclePoint(view.center, distance: distance, inParts: subViews.count)

    guard subViews.count == points.count, let uberView = view.superview else { // if the count is not the same or there is no superview: abort
        return
    }

    for (point, subView) in zip(points, subViews) { subView.center = point }
}
```

---

Notice how I did nothing except for the centre calculations in these functions. Styling them goes in another function. This makes it super easy to maintain and debug.

I might even let the last function just return the subviews with updated frames and add them later.

---

[image]

---

Or negative margin :)

[image]

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/romainmenke/14a52b61d7e91cb3bcdc)

Answer (score 2):

A full circle is 2 * pi radians.  You need to divide that by the number of items you have and multiply that by the index of the item you are currently processing.  Use trig to find the location on the circle:

```
for (index, users) in upimage.enumerate() {
    let radians = CGFloat(M_PI) * 2.0 / CGFloat(upimage.count) * CGFloat(index)

    ......

    let centerx = self.view.bounds.width / 2.0
    let radius =  currentuserpic.frame.size.width / 2.0
    let centery = self.view.bounds.height / 2.0

    let pointx = centerx + cos(radians) * radius
    let pointy = centery + sin(radians) * radius

    ......
}
```

Comment: I threw in some `CGFloat`s, including the one suggested by @RMenke (thanks!) in the calculation of `radians`.  Take a look.

Comment: It looks like when you move from 2 users to 3 users you are just adding more subviews without clearing out the previous ones.  You could keep an array of active subviews and call `removeFromSuperview` on them when you need to remove them.

Comment: Before adding new user buttons, clear out the old ones with `for button in userButton { button.removeFromSuperview() }; userButton = []`

Comment: I don't see any errors in the png you posted.  That code should be the first thing you do inside of `func locationsSet() {`.

Comment: That works thanks, but for some reason the buttons are not being evenly spaced  puu.sh/lTA5Y/da2ce9d364.png.

Comment: How many users buttons do you have at that point.  The picture you just posted looks exactly like the original problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97742/discussion-between-vacawama-and-stackerleet).